# Updating single row in SQLite Android Studio

Tags: android-sqlite

So I'm trying to update one row of my sql database with this following method

```
public boolean modiService(String name, String price, String updatename, String updateprice ){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, updatename);
    cv.put(COLUMN_RATE, updateprice);
    db.update(TABLE_SERVICE, cv, COLUMN_NAME + " = ?" , new String[] {name});
    return true;

}
```

However, whenever the function is called, it updates all the rows. I've tried to change the values within the "update" method called but I haven't been able to make it work

Comment: Perhaps try (as you are passing the original price and combination of name and price will be more specific) `return db.update(TABLE_SERVICE, cv, COLUMN_NAME + "=? AND " + COLUMN_RATE + "=?" , new String[]{name,price}) > 0;` (and delete the line `return true;` will then return false if no rows were updated).

Comment: It's still not working, for some reason it is not updating the database, I tried everything and it will not update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing intrinsically wrong with the code that you have shown. The example below, which utilises your exact code that you have shown, works.

**As such your issue is either with other unprovided code or with the method you are using to determine that no data has been updated.**

For this test the following was the code for the class that is subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper, in this case **ServiceDBHelper.java** :-

```
public class ServiceDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "service.db";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_SERVICE = "service";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_RATE = "rate";

    public ServiceDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String crt_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_SERVICE + "(" +
                COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COLUMN_RATE + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long insertService(String name, String price) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME,name);
        cv.put(COLUMN_RATE,price);
        return db.insert(TABLE_SERVICE,null,cv);
    }

    public boolean modiService(String name, String price, String updatename, String updateprice ){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, updatename);
        cv.put(COLUMN_RATE, updateprice);
        db.update(TABLE_SERVICE, cv, COLUMN_NAME + " = ?" , new String[] {name});
        return true;
    }

    public void logService(String description) {
        String TAG = "LOGSERVICE";
        Log.d(TAG,"Logging information for the Service Table for " + description);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_SERVICE,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        Log.d(TAG,"Number of rows in the " + TABLE_SERVICE + " table is " + String.valueOf(csr.getCount()));
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "Column " + COLUMN_NAME + " has a value of " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)) +
                    ".  Column " + COLUMN_RATE + " has a value of " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_RATE))
            );
        }
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

- As you can see the modiService method is as per you code.
- Other code has been added to :-

  - Create the table (named service) when the database is created.
  - Insert rows into the table to add some test data.
  - Write to data from the table to the log.

The following is the code used in an Activity to 
 - insert some rows, 
 - display the rows
 - update (modify a row)
 - display the rows

The code used in **MainActivity.java** was :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ServiceDBHelper mDBHlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBHlpr = new ServiceDBHelper(this);
        mDBHlpr.insertService("Fred","125.45");
        mDBHlpr.insertService("Mary","99.75");
        mDBHlpr.insertService("Harry","245.34");
        mDBHlpr.logService("After initial inserts");
        mDBHlpr.modiService("Mary","99.75","Susan","333.33");
        mDBHlpr.logService("After Updating Mary to Susan");
    }
}
```

The relevant output in the Log was :-

```
11-18 06:51:02.303 1212-1212/so53291104.so53291104 D/LOGSERVICE: Logging information for the Service Table for After initial inserts
11-18 06:51:02.303 1212-1212/so53291104.so53291104 D/LOGSERVICE: Number of rows in the service table is 3
11-18 06:51:02.303 1212-1212/so53291104.so53291104 D/LOGSERVICE: Column name has a value of Fred.  Column rate has a value of 125.45
11-18 06:51:02.303 1212-1212/so53291104.so53291104 D/LOGSERVICE: Column name has a value of Mary.  Column rate has a value of 99.75
11-18 06:51:02.303 1212-1212/so53291104.so53291104 D/LOGSERVICE: Column name has a value of Harry.  Column rate has a value of 245.34
11-18 06:51:02.307 1212-1212/so53291104.so53291104 D/LOGSERVICE: Logging information for the Service Table for After Updating Mary to Susan
11-18 06:51:02.307 1212-1212/so53291104.so53291104 D/LOGSERVICE: Number of rows in the service table is 3
11-18 06:51:02.307 1212-1212/so53291104.so53291104 D/LOGSERVICE: Column name has a value of Fred.  Column rate has a value of 125.45
11-18 06:51:02.307 1212-1212/so53291104.so53291104 D/LOGSERVICE: Column name has a value of Susan.  Column rate has a value of 333.33
11-18 06:51:02.307 1212-1212/so53291104.so53291104 D/LOGSERVICE: Column name has a value of Harry.  Column rate has a value of 245.34
```

As can be seen the row **Mary 99.75** has been changed using the **modiService** method to **Susan 333.33**.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help! The code works now, thank you very much!